# Is my ssd functioning okay?

Tags: ssd

I own a laptop with 256 gb ssd and 1 tb hdd. I used Crystal Disk Mark to analyse read and write speed of my ssd. While manually transferring data , i get write speed of 146 mbps. Is it normal??
[This is the result I get -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqubv.png)

Comment: What kind of data?

Comment: @gronostaj Just regular files like mix of videos , txt and other files!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's actually pretty fast, assuming data is going between SSD and HDD. The speed is constrained by the slower device, and 146mbyte/sec is fast for an HDD - presumably because its fairly fresh and using the faster outer tracks.

Comment: Okay i got it!! I was checking transfers between ssd and hdd. Now i did the same but both sides being the ssd and transfer speed was 530 mbps. I am satisfied. Thankyou for the answer!!

Comment: Does copying a file (e.g. a 2gb game) onto the same SSD also constrain the speeds? This is interesting because when I do that, I only get about a ~150mb/s transfer speed. Is *that* normal?

Comment: @pigeonburger I did copying to and from the same ssd and got 560 mbps, so maybe there is some problem!!

Comment: @chaitanya_12789 Is yours a special one you bought individually or do you have a *really* high end computer? Mine's just one that came with my laptop (a PC401 NVMe SK hynix 512gb). It's not an old computer, maybe about 3-4 years, and I bought it new about 1.5 years ago.

Comment: @pigeonburger No, i bought it with the laptop inbuilt. No i dont think my laptop is really high end. It is an hp pavilion gaming with amd ryzen. Maybe ssd behave like that with age? I cant say. but 1.5 yrs is not really old. I can only think this might happen if ssd is defragmented using procedures meant for hdds. but win 10 took care of that. Best ask a professional!

Comment: @pigeonburger I can confirm that SSDs do often slow down with age. There are a number of reasons for this including wear levelling and firmware. Although I only have a partial understanding of the mechanics. I was very surprised to find an earlier model 120gig SSD performing at slow hard drive speeds (in an office desktop) after a few years.

Comment: @davidgo Nevermind - I ran a few tests and easily got the write speed above 300. Guess it just depends what files I'm transferring!